# Detecting a user's currency in Objective-C for iPhone SDK... where to begin?

Tags: iphone, currency

I have an app that deals with currency, but obviously I'd like it to be multilingual. Where do I go about finding the value of what the user's default currency is? I presume it's as easy as a line or two of code, but I may be wrong...

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` probably has some useful information.  Try dumping that entire thing and see if you can find what you're looking for.

```
NSArray * domains = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainNames];
for (NSString * domain in domains) {
    NSDictionary * dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:domain];
    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", domain, dict);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at `NSLocale#objectForKey:` ?

Comment: +1 I'd never heard about `NSLocale` until I read your answer.  This is a much better solution than my suggestion!

Comment: Specifically, he'll want the objects returned for the NSLocaleCurrencySymbol and NSLocaleCurrencyCode keys.